# Use of undefined constant S - assumed "S"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here's the code, I need the
 **student_id** to auto increment and be in the format "S-0001","S-0002" etc

```
$table->increments('student_id', 6)->start_from(S-0000)->primary_key()->nullable(false);
```

If there is another method please share that, cause this is my homework from school.

Comment: you need to look into the difference between constants, variables, strings and numbers

Answer (score 0):

increments is a integer, cannot use a string key for all I know.

In Laravel documentation, it appears as "table->increments('id')" ==>   "Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER (primary key) equivalent column."

What you want to achieve maybe it is better if you add a prefix to the datatable for the key, or use a string (in that case you must control the incremental id yourself).